# declaration terminated incorrectly in c

Tags: c

I have written this code, but I am getting "declaration terminated incorrectly" error at line

```
int min(int a, int b){..}
```

The following is the code I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SIZE 10
#define WORD_SIZE 50
#define LIST_SIZE 500

typedef struct node
{
    char word[WORD_SIZE];
    int frequency[SIZE];
}node;
int no_of_words;

int filewords[SIZE];
int cluster[SIZE][SIZE];

void process(FILE *, node[], int);
void display(node[], int);
void generate_sim_mat(node [], double [][SIZE], int);
int build_cluster(double [][SIZE], int );
void disp(int);

int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    node word_list[LIST_SIZE];
    int num_files;
    int i;
    int cluster_count;
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[WORD_SIZE];
    double sim_mat[SIZE][SIZE];

    printf("Enter number of files:");
    scanf("%d", &num_files);

    for(i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", filename);

        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if(!fp)
        {
            printf("Could not open file:%s\n", filename);
            continue;
        }
        printf("File %s opened, Now processing it\n", filename);

        process(fp, word_list, i);
        fclose(fp);
    }
display(word_list, num_files);
generate_sim_mat(word_list, sim_mat, num_files);
cluster_count = build_cluster(sim_mat, num_files);
disp(cluster_count);
}

void disp(int cc)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < cc; i++)
    {
        printf("%d---", i);
        for(j = 1; j <= cluster[i][0]; j++)
            printf("%d ", cluster[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void display(node word_list[], int fnos)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < no_of_words; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t", word_list[i].word);
        for(j = 0; j < fnos; j++)
            printf("%d ", word_list[i].frequency[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void process(FILE *fp, node word_list[], int fno)
{
    char word[WORD_SIZE], ch;
    int i, j, k, word_count = 0;
    while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        k = 0;
        while(isalpha(ch))
        {
            word[k++] = tolower(ch);
            ch = getc(fp);
        }
        if(k > 0)
        {
            word_count++;
            word[k] = '\0';
            for(i = 0; i < no_of_words; i++)
                if(strcmp(word_list[i].word, word) == 0)
                {
                    word_list[i].frequency[fno]++;
                    break;
                }
            if(i == no_of_words)
            {
                strcpy(word_list[i].word, word);
                for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                    word_list[i].frequency[j] = 0;
                word_list[i].frequency[fno] = 1;
                no_of_words++;
            }
        }
    }
    filewords[fno] = word_count;
}

void generate_sim_mat(node word_list[], double sim_mat[][SIZE], int fno)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int sum;
    for(i = 0; i < fno; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < fno; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < no_of_words; k++)
                sum += min(word_list[k].frequency[i], word_list[k].frequency[j]);

            sim_mat[i][j] = sum/(sqrt(filewords[i]) * sqrt(filewords[j]));            
            printf("%.2lf ", sim_mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int build_cluster(double sim_mat[][SIZE], int fno)
{
    int cluster_count = 1;
    double threshold, sum, res;
    int i, j, k, l, flag;
    printf("Enter threshold value:");
    scanf("%.2lf", &threshold);

    cluster[0][0] = 1;
    cluster[0][1] = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < fno; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < cluster_count; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(k = 1; k <= cluster[j][0]; k++)
                sum += sim_mat[cluster[j][k]][i];
            res = sum / cluster[j][0];
            if(res >= threshold)
            {
                flag = 1;
                l = ++cluster[j][0];
                cluster[j][l] = i;
            }
        }
        if(!flag)
        {
            cluster[j][0] = 1;
            cluster[j][1] = i;
            cluster_count++;
        }
    }
    return cluster_count;
}
```

I am not able to debug this problem. Can someone tell me where the error is?

Comment: Your code compiles correctly except for this `scanf("%.2lf", &threshold);`, `scanf()` does not allow `'.'` in the format specifier, and specifying 2 will only read to characters, not what you think, you can't read a number with two decimals unless it's a string, and if it's a double that doesn't make much sense anyway. Also, your `main()` doesn't return anything, but nothing else is wrong with your code.

Comment: i changed `main()` return type from `int` to `void`. still the error persists.

Comment: i tried compiling this code on ideone online compiler and its compiling. but in tc its giving the declaration terminated incorrectly error?

Comment: why would you do that? it doesn't make any sense at all... `main()` has to return `int` you just had to make `main()` return a value, your compiler has to be broken, and you must post the exact error in the question otherwise there is no chance to help you.

Comment: Why don't you try to declare min function prototype first like for the others you did then implement it and compile again? Your code looks ok without doing this but maybe the compiler you are using now has a syntax issue about it. Give it a shot.

Comment: okay. thanks for the help. I changed the name of min to min1. and replaced all min to min1. now its functioning properly. maybe an issue with library function.

Comment: Yes, it looks min function prototype had been defined before in library and you were getting that error because of this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're compiling under Windows, you should be aware the `windef.h` (included by `windows.h`) defines `min` and `max` as macros. You can prevent this by defining `NOMINMAX` before including those files, such as with:

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

Or you can simply use a different function name other than `min`.

If you're *not* on Windows, it may still be that `min` is being defined somewhere in which case you should get the preprocessor output to see where, such as with `gcc -E ...`.